# Tridion 2013 JSP multiple value metadata only displaying single value

Tags: 2013, dxa, metadata, jsp

I inherited a Tridion 2013 page that has a metadata field set to "Embedded Schema", with "allow multiple values" checked.

I am trying to access these values on a JSP page from the `pageModel`.  The page model is just the default from DXA [com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.PageModel](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/master/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/api/model/PageModel.java)

`pageModel.meta` seems to be returning ONLY the first value, with the key and value sent as separate entries, and none of the additional values showing up at all.

In other words, if these were my values

> MultipleField
>   - exampleKey1 exampleValue1
>   - exampleKey2 exampleValue2
>   - exampleKey3 exampleValue3

and if this was my code (much simplified)

```
<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.PageModel" scope="request" />
<c:forEach var="meta" items="${pageModel.meta.entrySet()}">  
${meta.key}  ${meta.value}  
</c:forEach>
```

What I would get back would be

> MultipleFieldKey exampleKey1
>   MultipleFieldValue exampleValue1

None of the other values would show up at all.

Am I accessing this wrong?  Or was the metadata set up improperly in Tridion?

Comment: Is the field defined correctly, as a `List<>`, in the `pageModel`?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and add the source of your Page Model?

Comment: I added the PageModel source.  The meta field is a HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pageModel.meta` is defined for the HTML meta tags, it is actually not supposed to map to the CMS Page metadata.

For mapping CMS Page metadata, you should extend the default Page Model and add these fields yourself, just like you do in Entity Models.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something like that.  I'll give it a try and report back.